# Matching top view human detections with floor projection on interactive floor project

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm building an interactive floor. The main idea is to match the detections made with a Xtion camera with objects I draw in a floor projection and have them following the person.

I also detect the projection area on the floor which translates to a polygon. the camera can detect outside the "screen" area.

The problem is that the algorithm detects the the top most part of the person under it using depth data and because of the angle between that point and the camera that point isn't directly above the person's feet.

I know the distance to the floor and the height of the person detected. And I know that the camera is not perpendicular to the floor but I don't know the camera's tilt angle.

My question is how can I project that 3D point onto the polygon on the floor?

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I've been reading about camera projections but I'm not seeing how to use it in this particular problem.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

With the awnser from Diego O.d.L I was able to get an almost perfect detection. I'll write the steps I used for those who might be looking for the same solution (I won't get into much detail on how detection is made):

Step 1 : Calibration

- Here I get some color and depth frames from the camera, using openNI, with the projection area cleared.
- The projection area is detected on the color frames.
- I then convert the detection points to real world coordinates (using OpenNI's `CoordinateConverter`). With the new real world detection points I look for the plane that better fits them.

Step 2: Detection

- I use the detection algorithm to get new person detections and to track them using the depth frames.
- These detection points are converted to real world coordinates and projected to the plane previously computed. This corrects the offset between the person's height and the floor.
- The points are mapped to screen coordinates using a perspective transform.

Hope this helps. Thank you again for the awnsers.

Comment: When you say that you know the distance to the flor, do you know the distance to EACH corner of the rectangle you are measuring (or at least 3 points?)

Comment: I can get the camera's depth pixels at those points yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with the camera coordinate system initially. I'm assuming you don't have problems converting from `(row,column,distance)` to a real world system aligned with the camera axis `(x,y,z)`:

1. calculate the plane with three or more points (for robustness) with
   the camera projection (x,y,z). (choose your favorite algorithm,
   [i.e](http://www.ilikebigbits.com/blog/2015/3/2/plane-from-points)
2. Then Find the projection of your head point to the floor plane
   ([example](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html))
3. Finally, you can convert it to the floor coordinate system or just
   keep it in the camera system

From the description of your intended application, it is probably more useful for you to recover the image coordinates, I guess.

Comment: I was looking at what you sent me, Diego. Lets assume that the camera is perpendicular to the floor. If I get a plane for the floor and project any new detection points with the person's heigh wouldn't the projected point x, y coordinates be the same as the detection point x, y? Only the height would vary.

Comment: yes, the (x,y), _components_ would be the same, just the height (z component), would change. However, the (row,column) for the pixel in the image, would be different for different heights. The best example is this [image](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zPI1bQCyKrI/VCBttXbY7OI/AAAAAAAABTo/TYKJv-mA1F0/s1600/guy23.png). When the height of the camera is much, much larger than the height of the person, lets say for example, an aerial image, then the height of the person becomes irrelevant for the projeection. But in most situations, not

Comment: It worked really well. The final detection is almost perfect. Thank you very much Diego.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problems usually benefits from clearly defining the variables.

In this case, you have a head at physical position `{x,y,z}` and you want the ground projection `{x,y,0}`. That's trivial, but your camera gives you `{u,v,d}` (d being depth) and you need to transform that to `{x,y,z}`.

The easiest solution to find the transform for a given camera positioning may be to simply put known markers on the floor at `{0,0,0}, {1,0,0}, {0,1,0}` and see where they pop up in your camera.

Comment: I might be wrong but using markers won't account for different people with different heights

Comment: @PedroLeal: That's indeed true. Trivially to see: assume a camera at exactly {0,0,z} looking straight down at a person standing at {0,0,0}. Your depth camera will spot a head at {0,0,z-d}. You can figure out the persons height only if you know z, of vice versa. You had stated the problem was camera tilt, but if you need more variables you need more markers.